# FindViewById(R.id.toolbar) function cannot find Toolbar

Tags: android

I want to place a Spinner widget in the toolbar. Being a bit new to Android, Googled and found an example at https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/spinner-in-toolbar-android.php

with the following imports in activity main.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActiity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

and references in activity_main xml to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
...
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

These caused compilation errors. So, I changed to

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
in MainActivityjava    and to
<Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
...
</Toolbar>  in activity_main.xml.
```

This cleared the compilation errors.

But the Toolbar in '<Toolbar' was still displayed in red.
Clicked on it and message 'View requires API level 21
(current min is 16): ' appeared.
My android level/version is 29.

But, the main activity java gets stuck on the second statement

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

It does not return. I do not understand why.

Would be grateful for advice.

P.S. The link at the top contains all xml and java files for the example.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

your toolbar in xml file is different from the toolbar in main file
change the toolbar in xml file to be like this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```